# Assigning index values to a column with nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, assign

I am trying to assign values starting at 1 - length of the dataframe to a column that currently has all NaN values.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 
Also [don't provide datasets as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question), 
see [How to make pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) instead. Note to reduce the dataset to the necessary minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. Assuming Data frame names as `df`. if you want to start from `zero`

```
df['member_id'] = df.index
```

If you want to start from `1` (Your case)

```
df['member_id'] = df.index+1
```